# Android Studio 2.1.2 filenames without icons - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I upgraded **Ubuntu** from **15.10** to **16.04** and, as far as I remember, since then, the **icons** near the filenames in Project Structure in **Android Studio** have disappeared. It isn't very important, but it annoys me.

Here's the [screenshot]

[image]

Also, as it can be seen, the names of directories are becoming invisible. I think that this might be Ubuntu issue, as it has troubles with disappearing icons and text after waking up from sleeping mode (but this problem with Android Studio have **nothing** in common with sleeping mode).

Have you got any ideas or solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try reinstalling Android Studio package?. Imho, when we upgrading a distro there is a chance that an icon is accidently got removed.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to do that but I finally reinstalled Android Studio and it worked. Thanks

Comment: can we close this and making my comment accepted as answer?

Comment: @isnotmenow sure! but I cannot accept a comment, could you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Android Studio package will restore the icons. Imho, when we upgrading a distro there is a chance that an icon is accidently got removed.

Comment: It was working soon after reinstalling, but the problem is back.. I opened another project and lock icons disappeared and the color of directores became dark. Then I added a Java class and icons completely disappeared - just like before reinstalling.

Comment: It's really annoying.. Change you test using the other Android Studio theme instead your current theme?

Comment: Icons on 'light' theme are still invisible but I found out that (in Darcula theme) dark color on directory names was connected with changing font style in editor.. I also changed font size and style in Appearance settings after reinstalling, but after returning to defaults, icons didn't show up. When I open project, only the lock icon is missing, then, when I add one or two java class, both icons disappears.

Comment: Have you try first to uninstalling the package. Then install again.
Or could be the package isn't for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I've done it once again. It seems that it's working ;p

Comment: Well, I waiting for the good news..:P. Hope it work permanently :)